# Deploy a Visual Studio Community 2017 Asp.Net Core 2 project to remote IIS machine

Tags: c#, azure, asp.net-core, visual-studio-2017, asp.net-core-2.0

I've built an ASP.NET Core 2.0 MVC Web app on an OS X machine.  I'd like to deploy it to a Windows 2012 server with IIS, not to Azure.

Visual Studio for Mac 2017 Community edition only has the option to publish to an Azure service:

[image]

What things on the remote server need to be configured prior to deployment?  What are the step involved in the deployment?

Comment: have you read this ? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/publishing/iis?tabs=aspnetcore2x

Comment: I skimmed it.  I'm not sure that the community edition supports "publish profiles".  i'll need to read it more thoroughly, however.

Answer (score 0):

> I'd like to deploy it to a Windows 2012 server with IIS, not to Azure.

As you mentioned that Visual Studio for Mac 2017 Community only has publish to Azure option.

According to your description, my workaround is that you could use [dotnet publish](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-publish?tabs=netcore2x) command to publish  to a **local folder**.

I test it with Windows platform, you could try it on Mac. You are deploying to a remote server, you could **zip up** the files and move to the server. You also could refer to this [blog](https://stackify.com/how-to-deploy-asp-net-core-to-iis/) to get more detail info.

```
dotnet publish webprojectName.csproj --output localpath
```

[image]